# I need help figure out why this code doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple script put together that is supposed to look into a database and find a name. If it finds the name, it's supposed to output a message saying that someone is logged in. Yes, I do know that I am not actually logging someone in at this point in the code. Session has to be called and created etc.. I am not ready for all of that just yet.

So here is what I have.

The php:

```
   <?php

try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=interactive', 'root', '');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMEs "utf8"');
} catch (Exception $ex) {
$error = 'Failed to connect to the database <p>' . $ex->getMessage() . '</p>';
include '/includes/error.html.php';
exit();
}

$sql = 'SELECT name FROM members';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

foreach($result as $row)
{
    $user[] = array(
        'user' => $row['name']
    );
}

if (!isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $true = TRUE;
}
if (isset($_POST['username']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (in_array($username, $user)){
  $username .= ' You are logged in!!';
}


include 'form.php';
```

.
.
.
And here is the html:
.
.
.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>InteractiveForm</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username">
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
        <?php if (isset($_POST['username'])): ?>
        <?php echo $username; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've tried doing a print _r on $user, and it shows all of the names in the database as an associative array, so I thought that was good, but when I check to see if the name that I enter into the input exists, for some reason the in_array doesn't find it. If I am specific, and put in $user[0] it will find my name, but otherwise it won't.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated, especially with deep description!

Comment: typo in `$_POST['usernname']` -> `if (!isset($_POST['usernname']))`.

Comment: `$user=>user` is strange. Are you not getting some kind of error there?

Comment: Instead of `if (in_array($username, $user=>user)){` try `foreach($user as $row){ if($username == $row['user']){ $username .=  ... } }`

Comment: WHy use in_array() when you could use a "where" statement in the SQL? This is a good example of how not to use a database.

Comment: @Sean I found this error and fixed it but still no luck. I'll update my code here to reflect it and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Rasclatt That is something that looked strange to me to, and I was desperate lol. I've since changed it to just $user, since it "so I think" should be storing the full array I need.

Comment: If you still want to use `in_array()`, change to `foreach($result as $row){ $user[] = $row['name']; } if (in_array($username, $user)){ $username .= [...your message...];}`

Comment: @Sean, your suggesting of runnning through the results with the foreach was the one that worked. Thanks. Can you explain what was happening in my version and what I did wrong? The understanding is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @JoeLove I tried using the WHERE approach, but kept running into an error there too. 

'SELECT name FROM members
WHERE name = $_POST['username']'; is one way that I tried it.

I also tried 'SELECT name FROM members
WHERE name = :username'; and then created a prepared statement assinging :username to $_POST['username'] and it also created an error. 

Both of those error cases were the same, in saying that username was either undefined, or index wasn't found.

Comment: The reason is your original `$user` was a multidimensional array, so when you did `in_array` it was comparing to the array key `user`, not the nested user value. `in_array()` works with single level arrays.

Comment: @Sean I think I get what you are saying. So then, the first foreach that created $user was needed to build the multidimensional array first, and create blocks of data that related user to each name in the database. in_array looked for the first thing it found because that's just what it does and always found user instead of the name, and then the second foreach got more specific about what it was looking for, and created a list of just the names, and that's why it worked. Is that correct?

Comment: try 'SELECT name FROM members WHERE name ='.$_POST['username'];
instead. This is NOT the best appropach as it's a security issue, but once you get this code working, we can fix that problem easily. Let me know how this code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `prepare`->`fetch`->`execute` and couple other things notated below:

```
$sql    =   'SELECT name FROM members';
// Try prepare
$result =   $pdo->prepare($sql);
// Try execute
$result->execute();

// Loop with while and fetch
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        // no key, just values
        $user[] =   $row['name'];
    }

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];

        // Put this inside or else you will throw error on $username
        // if $_POST['username'] is not set
        if (in_array($username, $user)){
                echo strip_tags($username).' You are logged in!!';
            }
    }
else
    // Don't need to do another if, just use else here
    $true = true;
```

Also, as noted by *Joe Love*, you should use a `WHERE` clause in your sql instead of creating a giant array to check in. Something to think about!

**EDIT: The above scenario would look something like:**

```
$sql    =   "SELECT name FROM members where name = :username";
// Try prepare
$result =   $pdo->prepare($sql);
// Try execute with a bound parameter to guard against
// SQL injection
$result->execute(array(":username"=>$_POST['username']));

// Presumably, you should only get one hit, so you shouldn't need loop
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(isset($row['name'])) {
        echo strip_tags($row['name']).' You are logged in!!';
    }
else
    // Don't need to do another if, just use else here
    $true = true;
```

Comment: You fixed your typo before I could tell you about it lol, and yes,this it one working solution. Using the else to assign TRUE. Now why didn't I think of that! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I tried your code on my database, so I had changed a bunch of stuff and forgot what stuff I changed. :D

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite this using foreach instead of while? I am unaware of the difference between the two, and am more comfortable with foreach is why I ask.

Comment: My advice is not to try bypass something that is better suited just because you are not familiar with it. Best practice is to keep it and be familiar with it now that you've used it! In this instance `while()` is the best way to loop it. `foreach()` is better if you have a full array ready to iterate through.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I needed to hear! I just wasn't sure if it was possible too do the same efficiently with foreach. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Also, can you give an example of using a WHERE clause, because I tried it and it kept on giving me errors?

Comment: Ok, try my edit. I haven't tried it so let me know if it gives any errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. As pointed by sean , there seems to be an extra `n` in the `usernname` below code:

`if (!isset($_POST['usernname']))`

2. Please ignore my ignorance , but the 'action' in html doesn't have any value. Is it okay ?

Comment: (1) this is not an answer, (2) your 2. is not an issue. If the `action` value is empty the form will post to the same/current page.